# nuxt.js get default head in vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to get the head object that is configured by nuxt.config.js in a vue layout. In order to show the same title in an app bar as the page title.

I know that you can alter the page title with the head function in a vue component. But is it also possible to retrieve this information somehow?

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: head.titleTemplate // possible?
    }
  },
  head () {
      // here it is possible to change it but how about getting it?
  }
}
</script>
```

Another approach could be to get some data out of an page in the nuxt.config.js. But I think this is not how the hierarchy is structured.

Thanks for you help I am just starting to use javascript to code a website :)

Answer (score 0):

(If I understand you correctly) You can use the changed callback to keep track of the latest meta info used (and thus the title).

Example:

```
head() {
  return {
   changed: (info) => {
     this.title = info.title;
     console.log(info, info.title);
    },
  };
},
data() {
  return {
    title: '',
  };
},
```

Comment: The callback seems not being called because I don't get any console log nor does the title change.

Answer (score 0):

In `nuxt.config.js` before export I have setted variable with a string of the title.
Then added it to the `head` section and create a new `env` section:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/

```
const title = `Site title`
export default {
    head: {
        title
    },
    env: {
        title
    }
}
```

This how I'm getting the title in any Vue component:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    title () {
      return process.env.title
    }
  },
}
```

This helps you to keep your original title in `process.env.title`, even if you will want to change `head.title` dynamically.
Did anyone found a better solution maybe? :)